# Malloc array of pointers error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I have the following code:

```
    interface ** rInterfaces[MAX_REACTANS];
    _reaction->rInterfaces = (interface **)malloc(MAX_REACTANS * sizeof(interface *));
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct interface **[10]’ from type ‘struct interface **’
```

I don't know why I am getting this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `_reaction`? What is `_reaction->rInterfaces`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your `malloc` you want a pointer to a pointer to an interface. Drop `[MAX_REACTANS]` from your declaration. You can also drop the `interface **` cast.